# Can Motherboxes Open Boomtubes to Different Universes?

Tags: parallel-universe, dc

Someone recently made the assertion to me that Motherboxes in the DC Universe can open Boomtubes into different universes.

This was the first time that I had heard this claim.  I had always thought that Boomtubes were limited to locations within the current universe.  For example, in the Earth-2 universe, Motherboxes could open Boomtubes to any location within that universe, but could not open Boomtubes to any location in the Earth-3 universe.  I searched the Internet but could not find any definitive answer to the question.

Can Motherboxes open Boomtubes to different universes?

Comment: I'm no expert but given the boom tubes are associated with the New God's and they generally seem to be from another dimension (Fourth World) that seems to raise the possibility for multiverse travel - though I suspect you'd have found something if they were actually used that way.  Maybe the New God's universe is unique.

Comment: In Walt Simonson's *Orion* series, Orion gets trapped in a small, otherwordly dimension at one time. Can't remember if he came there through a boomtube, though.

Answer (score 6):

In *[JLA/Avengers #1](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/JLA/Avengers_Vol_1_1)*, the New God, Metron, gave the Avengers a Mother Box, which enabled them to travel from the Marvel universe to the DC universe.

> SCARLET WITCH: **We'll need a way to follow them--back to their world--**
>
> THOR: Ten tell us, enigmatic one--tell us how we might find these fiends!
>
> IRON MAN: Skip it, Thor--I'm sure he's taken a "vow of mystery," or something--these types always do. Maybe I can adapt the modulator... infuse us with their world's base signature, and...
>
> METRON: It is not necessary, Iron Man... any more than are Thor's threats. **Here. She will aid you.**
>
> [image: JLA/Avengers #1, page 39]
>
> [image: JLA/Avengers #1, page 40]
>
> <sub>*JLA/Avengers #1* (September, 2003)</sub>

In *[Avengers/JLA #2](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Avengers/JLA_Vol_1_2)*, Darkseid also used his [Omega Beams](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Omega_Beams) to transport several heroes from [Apokolips](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Apokolips) to the [Savage Land](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Savage_Land).

This appears to be contradicted by *[Unlimited Access #4](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Unlimited_Access_Vol_1_4)*, however, in which Darkseid indicated that he needed [Access](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Axel_Asher_(Marvel_Universe)) -- a human with the power to travel between the Marvel and DC universes -- to open a portal to enable him and his forces to return home from the Marvel universe.

> DARKSEID: Prepare your portal. I will gather the gods and you will send us back to our proper time and universe.
>
> [image: Unlimited Access #4, page 35]
>
> [image: Unlimited Access #4, page 36]
>
> <sub>*Unlimited Access #4* (March, 1998)</sub>